# My Football application app always prints the same answer. Is there something wrong with it?

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

url = "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/E0.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(url)

le = LabelEncoder()
data["FTR"] = le.fit_transform(data["FTR"])

predictors = ["HomeTeam", "AwayTeam", "FTHG", "FTAG"]

model_data = data[predictors]

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(model_data[["FTHG", "FTAG"]], data["FTR"])

home_team = "Arsenal"
away_team = "Bournmouth"
home_goals = 2
away_goals = 1

prediction_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "HomeTeam": [home_team],
        "AwayTeam": [away_team],
        "FTHG": [home_goals],
        "FTAG": [away_goals],
    }
)

result = model.predict(prediction_data[["FTHG", "FTAG"]])[0]

result_str = le.inverse_transform([int(result)])[0]

if result_str == "H":
    print(f"{home_team} wins!")
elif result_str == "A":
    print(f"{away_team} wins!")
else:
    print("It's a draw!")
```

Hi guys,

I've tried to create my own Football predicting app using python.  It does run, but always returns with "It's a draw!" for all results.  How can I make sure that the results vary based on previous matches played?  Just to clarify, in my code: FTHG, FTAW and FTR stand for 'full time home game', 'full time away game' and 'full time result'

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed the value of `result_str`.

Comment: Your target seems to be categorical (_H_, _A_, _else_), but you are doing linear regression. Maybe you wanted to do logistic regression instead?

Comment: don't know how your model train but I have find some results..! if `home_goals=2,away_goals=-2` Output `Aresenal Wins`   if `home_goals=1,away_goals=3` `Bournmouth wins!` if `h_g=3,a_g=2` it's `draw`..